# Php nusoap not passing content

Tags: php, mysql, nusoap

I'm new around this corner as well as programming. I'm trying to create a web service based on nusoap and php so it passes a few values from a mysql database out. 
I have looked around many websites (including stack overflow answers) and i found some solutions that i have tried but yet without success. For some reason when i do the client to access the service it always comes empty. After a day looking at this i only see letters now...

If someone could provide a way to a solution i would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**Server Side**

```
<?php
    include 'nusoap.php';

    $server=new nusoap_server();
    $server->configureWSDL("demo"."urn:demo");


    $server->register(
            'gamedata', 
            array(),    
            array("estadio"=>'xsd:string',
                  "nome"=>'xsd:string',
                )
            );

    function gamedata(){
        $con=mysql_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '') or die ("Erro ao conectar...");
        mysql_select_db("testar",$con) or die ("Erro ao seleccionar DB...");

        $queryforestadio="SELECT nome,cidade FROM estadio";
        //$queryforjogos = "SELECT data, id_selecao1, id_selecao2 FROM jogo";

        while($resultestadio = mysql_fetch_array($queryforestadio)){
      $estadios[] = array('nome'=>$resultestadio['nome'],
                          'cidade'=>$resultestadio['cidade'],
                          ); 
          echo "Message from function: ".$estadios['nome']['cidade'];
    }
    return $estadios;

    }
    if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) ) $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA =file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

?>
```

**Client Side**

```
<?php    

        require('nusoap.php');
        $client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost:8048/webservice/index.php');
        $response= $client->call('gamedata');



    $r = $response;
    $count = count($r);

    for($i=0; $i<=$count-1;$i++){
        echo "This is name: ".$r[$i]['nome'];
        echo "This is city: ".$r[$i]['cidade'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is pointless/redundant:

```
  $estadios[] = array('nome'=>$resultestadio['nome'],
                      'cidade'=>$resultestadio['cidade'],
                      );
```

You're only fetching the `nome` and `cidade` fields in your query, so `$resultstadio` is already an array of just those two fields and their values.

And then this does NOT match the structure you're building above:

```
      echo "Message from function: ".$estadios['nome']['cidade'];
```

You probably should have something more like this:

```
while($resultestadio = mysql_fetch_array($queryforestadio)){
    $estadios[] = $resultestadio;
    echo "Message from function: ".$resultestadio['nome'] ',' . $resultestadio['cidade'];
```